# Whats the best place to make the upload of a file before saving data

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a simple form with some data to be saved to database but on this form I also have a file field.

I would to know what is the best place to make the upload of the file.

I thought to do it on `beforeSave()` but I dont have acces to `$this->request->data('file_name')` on `beforeSave()`.

Answer (score 0):

BeforeSave is for pre-save logic (validations, etc). You better use afterSave() for upload the file.

Comment: 2 thigs, firt: on beforeSave() i still dont have access to request->save('file_name'). Second: I cant upload after save because if my upload fail I have no way to rollback the save

Comment: Also there *are* valid scenarios where you want to save the file itself before you save the DB record. If it's critical the file was upload and some checks or pre-processing done on it for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like this one instead of inventing your own way of handling uploads:

https://github.com/davidyell/CakePHP3-Proffer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/tree/3.0) as well or take a look at it how it does it.

https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/tree/3.0

The plugin allows you to configure when you want to store the file:

> Every developer might want to store the file at a different point or
>   apply other operations on the file before or after it is store. Based
>   on different circumstances you might want to save an associated file
>   even before you created the record its going to get attached to, in
>   other scenarios like in this documentation you might want to do it
>   after.

The plugin is using events for manipulating files before they get saved.